# How do I pass both the list and the user's number to a function and have it display all numbers in the list that are greater than the user's number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to pass both the list and the user's number to a function and have it display all numbers in the list that are greater than the user's number. This is as far as I've gotten and am stuck. Thanks for any tips.

```
import random

def randnum():
    random_num = [random.randrange(1,101,1) for _ in range (20)]
    random_num.sort()
    return random_num

def usernum():
    try:
        user_num = int(input("Please enter a number 1 through 100: "))
        if user_num > 100 or user_num < 1:
            print("Please try again.")
            usernum()
    except ValueError:
        user_num = print("Error. Please try to use integers while entering a number 1-100")
        usernum()
    return user_num

def main():
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing some code, but your function could be something like that :

```
def getHigherNumbers(userNumber, listNumbers):
    return [x for x in listNumbers if x > userNumber]
```

Also there is a bug in your `usernum()`:

When there is an error you should use `return usernum()` instead of just `usernum()` since there'll be recursion.

To answer your question in the comments, here is how your code could look :

```
import random

def randnum():
    random_num = [random.randrange(1,101,1) for _ in range (20)]
    random_num.sort()
    return random_num

def usernum():
    try:
        user_num = int(input("Please enter a number 1 through 100: "))
        if user_num > 100 or user_num < 1:
            print("Please try again.")
            return usernum()
    except ValueError:
        print("Error. Please try to use integers while entering a number 1-100")
        return usernum()
    return user_num

def getHigherNumbers(user_num, random_num):
    return [x for x in random_num if x > user_num]

def main():
    random_num = randnum()
    print('random nums : %s' % random_num)
    user_num = usernum()
    print('user num : %s' % user_num)
    greater_nums = getHigherNumbers(user_num, random_num)
    print('greeter numbers : %s' % greater_nums)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


# random nums : [1, 4, 11, 14, 18, 24, 27, 29, 31, 37, 37, 41, 45, 59, 59, 66, 83, 87, 90, 99]
# Please enter a number 1 through 100: 12
# user num : 12
# greeter numbers : [14, 18, 24, 27, 29, 31, 37, 37, 41, 45, 59, 59, 66, 83, 87, 90, 99]
```

Comment: Am I right by returning both the random_num and user_num out of both functions? How can I manipulate the data once I call the functions?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, please complete your code, `main()` is empty, then show what you try, what doesn't work, and what you expect.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to explain better. I am having trouble finishing my main() at the moment. Do I have to call the `randnum()` and `usernum()` functions inside my `main()` to then find out if the numbers in the list are greater than the user's entered number?

Comment: exactly, I've edited my answer to show you how you could do that.

Comment: I think the point you are missing is that you can affect values returned by functions to variables.
for example if you create a function `myFunc()` that ends with : `return 12`, then doing something like `a = myFunc()` will put 12 in `a`.
See ?

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Thanks a ton Loïc.

Comment: One more thing, If I wanted to display a message that would show if there were no numbers from the list higher than the user's number would I do something similar to:                                                                             
  `if greater_nums is []:
        print("There were no numbers greater than", user_num)`

Comment: Close : `if len(greater_nums) == 0: ...` or `if greater_nums == []`